# How do you get the files type/extension based on the file content in ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mime-types

How do you get the file type/extension based on the file content in ActionScript? For example I have a jpg image with the following file name: niceimage. Just based on the file name, I won't know whats the files extension but for me it's important to know the exact type of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to read in the binary data (https://www.google.com/search?q=read+binary+file+in+as3) and parse the image header yourself.

There are also libraries out there (such as http://www.greensock.com/loadermax/) that can help if you only care about loading the content to your scene.